# Call a function when a State variable is changed / Segmented Control is toggled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to work out how to **call a function** to update a firebase database **when a segmented control is toggled.** Any ideas? Tried **didSet()**, but doesn't seem to work.

**Variable**

```
@State var exteriorIndex = 1
```

**Segmented Control:**

```
Picker("Numbers", selection: $exteriorIndex) {
                ForEach(0 ..< exteriorOptions.count) { index in
                    Text(self.exteriorOptions[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .frame(width: 950/2, height: 78/2)
```

**DataUpdate()** *Function (that needs to be called)*

```
func dataUpdate() {
    print("DataUpdate Running..")

    var exterior = false
    if exteriorIndex == 1 {
        exterior = true
    }

    else {
        exterior = false
    }

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("settings").document("LI").setData([
        "exterior": exterior
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Picker("Numbers", selection: Binding<Int>(
    get: { self.exteriorIndex },
    set: {
            self.exteriorIndex = $0
            self.dataUpdate()
    }) {
    ...
```